# How are the two independent states of polarization of photon related to the two helicity states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-spin, poincare-symmetry, helicity

**(1)** In the canonical quantization of the free electromagnetic field, the Coulomb gauge condition $$A^0=0,~~ \nabla\cdot\textbf{A}=0\tag{1}$$ implies that the polarization vector $\epsilon^\mu$ satisfies $$\epsilon^0=0,~~\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\cdot\hat{\textbf{p}}=0\tag{2}$$ which says that the electromagnetic field has two independent transverse states of polarization.

**(2)** From the representation theory of Poincare group, it is known that for photons $\textbf{S}\cdot\hat{\textbf{p}}$ has eigenvalues $h=\pm 1$ where $\textbf{S}$ denotes the spin operator.

Both the descriptions above make it clear that the electromagnetic field has two independent degrees of freedom. The description **(1)** says the electromagnetic field has *two independent states of polarization* and the description **(2)** says that it has *two independent helicity states*.

---

**Question**

$\bullet$ *Does it mean states of polarization are identical to states of helicity?*

$\bullet$ *Is there is a unique one-to-one correspondence between the states of helicity and the independent states of polarization? In that case, $h=+1$ corresponds to which polarization and $h=-1$ corresponds to which? How can such a correspondence, if exists, be understood?*

A similar question was asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213808/spin-and-polarization-qm-vs-qft).

Comment: Polarization vectors are the photon wave-functions (in momentum space) corresponding to states of a given helicity.

Comment: because the photon has zero mass and spin one, there are only two possible states +1 to the direction of motion  and -1 to the direction of motion.look at the figures in this link to see the connection between the polarization of a light wave and the spin of the photon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light

Answer (score 1):

States of definite helicity are states of definite spin measured along a particular axis. You can, in principle, use any axis to define your spin eigen-basis, it's just not commonly done because the result isn't Lorentz invariant and you have to be careful about what spins are forbidden by the lack of a helicity 0 state. It can be shown that there is a unique one to one mapping between the choice of spin basis and the polarization state basis. The polarization vectors, $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_\lambda$, handle that mapping (the $\lambda$ indices exist in spin/polarization space, and the spatial index exists in physical space).

Comment: _"It can be shown that there is a unique one to one mapping between the choice of spin basis and the polarization state basis. "_ Can you show this or suggest a reference? @SeanE.Lake

Comment: The polarization of a wave is set by a linear combination of the $\mathbf{\epsilon}_r$, right? The index $r$ lives in helicity space, and the vector components of each $\mathbf{\epsilon}$ live in physical/polarization space. In other words, you assume this to be the case when you use $\mathbf{\epsilon}_r$. @SRS

Answer (score 0):

In the radiation gauge, the 3-vector potential has the most general Fourier mode expansion given by $$\textbf{A}(\textbf{x})=\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E_{\textbf{p}}}}\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2}[\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_r(\textbf{p})a_{\textbf{p},r}e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{x}}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^*_r(\textbf{p})a^\dagger_{\textbf{p},r}e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{x}}].\tag{1}$$ Using the definition of *spin operator* $$S^{ij}=\int d^3\textbf{x}:(A^i\partial_0 A^j-A^j\partial_0 A^i):$$ and Eq.(1), one obtains after performing the integral over space
$$S^{ij}=i\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\sum\limits_{r,s}[\epsilon_r^i(\textbf{p})\epsilon_s^{j*}(\textbf{p})-\epsilon_s^{i*}(\textbf{p})\epsilon_r^j(\textbf{p})]a^\dagger_{\textbf{p},r}a_{\textbf{p},s}.$$
The action of the spin operator $S^{ij}$, as obtained in Eq. (2), on a one-particle state $a^\dagger_{\textbf{k},m}|0\rangle$, one finds, $$S^{ij}a^\dagger_{\textbf{k},m}|0\rangle=i\sum\limits_{s=1}^{2}\Bigg[\epsilon_m^i(\textbf{p})\epsilon_s^{j*}(\textbf{k})-\epsilon_s^{i*}(\textbf{k})\epsilon_m^j(\textbf{k})\Bigg]a^\dagger_{\textbf{k},s}|0\rangle.$$

Let us choose $\textbf{k}=(0,0,k)$ so that the helicity is measured by $\textbf{S}\cdot\hat{\textbf{k}}=S^3=S^{12}$. We choose, $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{1}(\textbf{k})=1/\sqrt{2}(1,i,0)$ and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{2}(\textbf{k})=1/\sqrt{2}(1,-i,0)$. Therefore, $$S^3a^\dagger_{\textbf{k},1}|0\rangle=(+1)a^\dagger_{\textbf{k},1}|0\rangle,\\
S^3a^\dagger_{\textbf{k},2}|0\rangle=(-1)a^\dagger_{\textbf{k},2}|0\rangle.$$

**Conclusion** *A one-particle state with right circular polarization corresponds to helicity $+1$, and the one-particle state with left-circular polarization corresponds to a state with helicity $-1$*.

---

### Update

The electric field is given by $$\textbf{E}(\textbf{x})=-\frac{\partial\textbf{A}}{\partial t}=(-i)\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{\frac{E_\textbf{p}}{2}}\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2}[\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_r(\textbf{p})a_{\textbf{p},r}e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^*_r(\textbf{p})a^\dagger_{\textbf{p},r}e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{x}}].\tag{2}$$ and

$$\textbf{B}(\textbf{x})=\nabla\times\textbf{A}=(i)\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{\frac{E_\textbf{p}}{2}}\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2}[\hat{\textbf{p}}\times\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_r(\textbf{p})a_{\textbf{p},r}e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{x}}-\hat{\textbf{p}}\times\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^*_r(\textbf{p})a^\dagger_{\textbf{p},r}e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{x}}].\tag{3}$$ where I used the fact that $E_{\textbf{p}}=|\textbf{p}|$. Using $\hat{\textbf{p}}=(0,0,1)$, it should be easily checked that the operators $\textbf{E}\pm i\textbf{B}$ acting on the vacuum $|0\rangle$ respectively creates one-particle states of photon with right-circular and left-circular states of polarization. I'm lazy to work out the algebra.

**Reference** A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory-Michele Maggiore.